# Difference between CharSequence and Sequence<Char> in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, sequence, charsequence

In `Kotlin`, a `Sequence<T>` is a container whose operations on it (like map, filtering, etc..) are done lazily. Like Java `Streams`.

A `CharSequence` is just a supertype/interface of several String-like types, like `String`, `StringBuilder`, etc..

So a `CharSequence` is not processed lazily, right? It's processed greedily.

It just (unfortunately) happens that `Kotlin` chose the name `Sequence` to refer to "streams", but also inherited the term/type `CharSequence` from `Java`, thereby creating some confusion.

Am I right?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Java has a similar case with `java.io.InputStream`/`java.io.OutputStream` and `java.util.stream.Stream`.

Comment: A `CharSequence` isn't a supertype, it's an *interface* - I'm pointing this out because *a lot of wildly different stuff* can implement `CharSequence`, and the actual implementation of how it produces `char`s and `String` representations is entirely up to the object - they *could* be lazily produced! A *sequence* is just a mathematical term for a ordered series of values, finite or infinite, which is technically what the Kotlin version is - as opposed to a `List` which is a finite series. You'll see a lot of language borrowed from the functional, mathematical side (e.g. `map`)

Comment: Right. Thanks. I think it depends on how peeky we want to get with the definition. I am defining a "supertype" as either a superclass or an interface. I've seen the usage of that term in that way. But I'll clarify.

Comment: This is an unfortunate situation where similar interface names doesn’t indicate any similarity in behavior or relationship. I think the Kotlin designers were out of possible names because CharSequence was already part of a Java and they needed a good word for succinctly describing their alternative to Java Streams.